# Optimizing scala-spark code by removing "for loop"

Tags: scala

I wanted to optimize this code ( scala spark) to remove for loop . How do i do it ?

```
var varianceExplained = Array[(Int,Double)]();
var varExplained = Array[(Double)]();//{This one contains double values assigned before}
var sums = 0.00
for(x<-0 to varExplained.length-1)
{sums =sums+varExplained(x) 
 varianceExplained +:= (x,sums)
}
```

Comment: What type is `varExplained`?

Comment: Added the explanation. thanks

Comment: What kind of optimization do you have in mind when you say "optimizing by removing for loop"? You cannot do what you are doing (cumulative sum calculation) without looping through the array `varExplained` in `O(N)`. Also,  why do you mention spark? Are you asking how can this process be parallelized (and hence *possibly* made faster) by using spark?

Comment: Yes  I want to parallelize in spark  if possible. I cant avoid loops in scala

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how you would parallelize a set which is reliant on its preceding values... only this I can add is how to remove loops and make it a recursive function as per functional programming best practices.

```
  def go(acc: Array[(Int, Double)], iter: Int, sums: Double): Array[(Int, Double)] ={
    if (iter == varExplained.length)acc
    else {
      go((iter, sums+varExplained(iter)) +: acc, iter+1, sums+varExplained(iter))
    }
  }
  go(Array[(Int, Double)](), 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to convert the for loop to a translation of `map`.
You can try the following:

`val varianceExplained = varExplained.map(elem => (elem, sums+varExplained(elem)))`.

In this case you do not need the **varianceExplained** array. You get the required `Array[(Int, Double)]` as a result of the `map` operation. I have used similar strategies at work to make my code efficient.
Also, do try using `vals` instead of `vars` in your code.